# How do access pylint report

Tags: python, maya, pylint, python-3.9

I am attempting to use pylint to see what score I get for my simple program. I run the code in the command prompt and that is all it does.I am looking for my code rating. Code below:

pylint file:///C:/Users/Tre/OneDrive/Documents/University Work/SDEV 360/Week 1 Discussion.py

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Dhould work with `pylint file:///C:/Users/Tre/OneDrive/Documents/University Work/SDEV 360/Week 1 Discussion.py -s yes -r yes`

See `pylint --help`